# How to animate GMSMarker?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

How i can perform animation like this in GMSMarker?
I tried to add layer to GMSMarker layer but it doesn't work..

```
        let pulse = Pulsing(center: CGPoint(x: 240, y: 480),radius: 36, fillColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9979501367, green: 0.7617542744, blue: 0.05507106334, alpha: 0.5), strokeColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9979501367, green: 0.7617542744, blue: 0.05507106334, alpha: 1), lineWidth: 1)
        pulse.animationDuration = 0.8

        fromLoctionMarker.layer.addSublayer(pulse)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created five circles
and lunch timer for every circle and animate circle border circle opacity color and circle radius changing smoothly using timer
use recursive to make the animation infinity

```
// marker animation variables
private var numberOfCircels = 0
private var circlesTimers = [Timer]()
private var circlesRadius = [Int]()
private var circlesColors = [CGFloat]()
private var circlesBorderColors = [CGFloat]()
private var gmsCircles = [[GMSCircle]]()


private func createCircel(){
        if numberOfCircels == 5 { return }
        let tempNumberOfCircels = numberOfCircels
        let circleTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerFiredForCircel), userInfo: ["currentIndex": tempNumberOfCircels], repeats: true)
        circlesTimers.append(circleTimer)
        circlesRadius.append(0)
        gmsCircles.append([GMSCircle]())
        circlesColors.append(0.2)
        circlesBorderColors.append(0.7)
        numberOfCircels = numberOfCircels + 1
        print(numberOfCircels, "numberOfCircels")
    }



   @objc
    private func timerFiredForCircel(timer: Timer){
        guard let context = timer.userInfo as? [String: Int] else { return }
        guard let currentIndex = context["currentIndex"] else { return }
        let location = order.fromLocation.location
        let circel = GMSCircle(position: location, radius: CLLocationDistance(circlesRadius[currentIndex]))
        circel.fillColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.7607843137, blue: 0.05882352941, alpha: 1).withAlphaComponent(circlesColors[currentIndex])
        circel.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.7607843137, blue: 0.05882352941, alpha: 1).withAlphaComponent(circlesBorderColors[currentIndex])
        circel.strokeWidth = 1
        gmsCircles[currentIndex].append(circel)
        if circlesRadius[currentIndex] < 150{
            circlesRadius[currentIndex] += 3
            circlesColors[currentIndex] -= (0.2 / 50)
            circlesBorderColors[currentIndex] -= 0.014
        }else if circlesRadius[currentIndex] >= 150{
            circlesRadius[currentIndex] = 0
            circlesColors[currentIndex] = 0.2
            circlesBorderColors[currentIndex] = 0.7
        }
        circel.map = googleMab
        for i in 0..<gmsCircles[currentIndex].count - 1{
            let circle = gmsCircles[currentIndex][i]
            circle.map = nil
            gmsCircles[currentIndex].removeAll(where: { $0 == circle})
        }
        if circlesRadius[currentIndex] == 30{
            self.createCircel()
        }
    }
```